# Playing videos in background on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1, mediaelement

I'm creating a Windows Phone 8.1 app to play music and video from URIs. I first used a `MediaElement` control, to play media content.

However I can't play video or audio when my app is switched to background. I've implemented [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/BackgroundAudio-63bbc319/view/SourceCode#content) (with  `BackgroundMediaPlayer`) but this sample can only play audio, and I want my app to play video too.

I've searched a lot on the Internet, but I couldn't find the answer I'm looking for. So my question is : How can I play video in my app when it's switched to background?

Comment: What does it mean to play a video when your app is not visible (i.e. it is in the background)?

Comment: I mean when your app is not visible, I want the video sound to be played. But I'd like to see the video again when I switch back to foreground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If BackgroundMediaPlayer can't play video files in background I am almost sure there is no way to do it. That looks a little bit strange to play video in background.

But if your app is switched to the foreground, you can continue play video. Just save the last file in the [mostRecentlyUsedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207458) to have permissions to access this file the next time the app is opened.

```
Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.Add(yourfile);
```

And later you can get it with:

```
String lastfilemruFirstToken = StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.Entries.FirstOrDefault().Token;
StorageFile lastfile = await StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.GetFileAsync(lastfilemruFirstToken);
```

The position you can get and set with the [MediaElement.Position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.position) property